# Maven version plugin only working the second time

Tags: maven

We have set the maven version plugin like this:

```
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <properties> 
      <myVersion>1.2.3</myVersion>
    </properties>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <newVersion>${myVersion}</newVersion>
                    <generateBackupPoms>false</generateBackupPoms>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>set</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

However the artifact created is at its original version (1.0.0) and only after the first run it is updated. I think it's because when the plugin updates the pom it is already too late as the file is being read on the mvn package command.
Is there some kind of trick to avoid performing 2 subsequent maven commands?

Comment: No. But if you goal is to supply a version number per parameter, there are better alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to execute the version plugin via command line e.g.:

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.3-SNAPSHOT
```

The documentation of [versions:set](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html) also says:

> **Description:**
>
> Sets the current project's version and based on that change propagates that 
>   change onto any child modules as necessary.
>
> **Attributes:**
>
> - Requires a Maven project to be executed.
> - Executes as an aggregator plugin.
> - **Executes by direct invocation only.**
> - The goal is thread-safe and supports parallel builds.

I think *by direct invocation only* means you need to execute it via command line.